# Picking a chosen amount of things from a table without repetition

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm currently working on a little side project, so this is my first time learning LUA and I'm currently stuck. So what I'm trying to do is create a function that will randomly choose two numbers between 1 and 5 and make it so they can not collide with the player. I can not seem to get the ability to chose two numbers at random without them being the same. I've been looking around, but have not been able to find a clear answer. Any help would be much appreciated!

My code so far:

```
local function RandomChoice1()
    local t = {workspace.Guess1.CB1,workspace.Guess1.CB2,workspace.Guess1.CB3,workspace.Guess1.CB4,workspace.Guess1.CB5}
    local i = math.random(1,5)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select one with probability 20% (one from 1..5 range) and the second one with probability 25% (one from 1..5 range minus the first choice), then something like this should work:

```
local i1 = math.random(1,5) -- pick one at random from 1..5 interval
-- shift the interval up to account for the selected item
local i2 = math.random(2,5) -- pick one at random from 2..5 interval
-- assign 1 in case of a collision
if i2 == i1, then i2 = 1 end
```

This will guarantee the numbers not being equal and satisfying your criteria.

Comment: Is there a way to loop the i2 until it's different from i1 rather than just setting it to a specific one?

Comment: You sure can, but there is no need to. It's guaranteed to be unique and the code is going to be simpler/shorter than the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating i2 you can generate difference `i2 - i1`

```
local i1 = math.random(5)   -- pick one at random from 1..5 interval
local diff = math.random(4) -- pick one at random from 1..4 interval
local i2 = (i1 + diff - 1) % 5 + 1  -- from 1..5 interval, different from i1
print(i1, i2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion. Save the previous number and if it's the same just generate a new one until its not the same. This way you are garaunteed to never have the same number twice.

```lua
local i = 0;

function ran(min,max)
 local a = math.random(min,max);

  if (a == i) then
    return ran(min,max);
  else
    i = a;
    return a;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: "2 from 5" without doubles...

```
local t = {}

for i = 1, 5 do
  t[i] = i                               
end

-- From now a simple table.remove()...
-- ( table.remove() returns the value of removed key/value pair )
-- ...on a random key avoids doubles

for i = 1, 2 do
  print(table.remove(t, math.random(#t)))
end
```

Example output...

```
1
4
```